# How to get rid of new carpet removed from a new house

Tags: carpet

I live in Sugar Land, Texas within city of Houston. I ripped off the newly installed carpet from a new house to install wood floor. What are the best way to get rid off the carpet and pad in my garage?

Answer (score 12):

If it is still in an okay state, you can try and sell it for a small price on your local [classified ad](http://houston.ebayclassifieds.com/) site.

Some contractors may look for that kind of stuff, or some other DIYers may use it to finish a small area.

Comment: Try also https://groups.freecycle.org/group/HoustonFreecycle/posts/all

Answer (score 8):

Start by contacting your local waste management provider, either by phone or on the web. They will be able to tell you if they'll take it, and how you need to prepare it.  If they don't take it, they should be able to direct you to a local company who will.

Every area is different. The best way to get a straight answer, is to go right to the source.

According to [Sugar Land, TX Garbage & Recycling Guidelines](http://www.sugarlandtx.gov/index.aspx?NID=517)

> **Carpeting**
>   Residents can set carpeting out during their bulky item collection. Carpeting must be cut in 4 foot strips for pickup, and can not weigh over 50 pounds. Another option is to have the carpet installer dispose of your old carpet. You may be able to dispose of this item at a local landfill for a fee.
>
> [Source](http://www.sugarlandtx.gov/index.aspx?NID=1276#c)
>
> **Bulky Waste**
>   Bulky waste service is provided once a month for items too large to fit in the garbage cart. Bulky waste does not include construction, demolition or hazardous wastes.
>
> ***Guidelines***
>
> - Set your bulky items out by 7 a.m. on your collection day but no earlier than 6 p.m. the evening before.
> - Bulky items should be set out at the curb at least four feet from other objects.
>     -Do not place items in your garbage cart for bulky waste collection. Items should be placed directly on the curb.
>
> [Source](http://www.sugarlandtx.gov/index.aspx?NID=518)

If you don't want to wait for regular collection, you can call to schedule a pickup.

> **On-Call Bulky Waste Service**
>   Residents who do not wish to hold bulky items until their next bulky waste day can contact Republic Services Customer Service at 713-726-7307 to schedule an additional pickup. This service is subject to the following fees which must be paid prior to scheduling the service.
>
> **Fees**
>
> - Less than 5 cubic yards - $75
> - Greater than 5 cubic yards - Call for pricing

Answer (score 2):

You can cut it up into narrow strips to roll up & put out with the regular trash to get rid of it quite slowly...please don't kill the trash guys with a mountain of trash.

Or, call Habitat For Humanity, Salvation Army, Goodwill or whatever's in your area. Some of those are looking for nice new carpet & will gladly remove it.

Bravo on getting that filth out of the house. Carpet was the worst idea ever.

Comment: Animal shelters may also have a use for clean carpet, to cover cat trees.

Comment: F cats! Kidding, that's actually a good point. I wonder if they take couches & drapes.

Comment: _Nobody___ takes couches these days, excel maybe Goodwill and only if you bring it to a rework center. I'm presuming that is due to fear of bedbugs, or maybe the general problem of getting to much stuff that really wasnt worth repairing even as an exercise in furniture repair.

Comment: I was kidding! But, I guess you had to be there. You're right, it's illegal for used upholstered furniture to be re-sold.

Answer (score 2):

If it's indeed new, roll the larger sections neatly and place it on the curb. There's a good chance it'll be gone in a day. Plenty of folks are looking for basement floor rugs, etc. You'll be doing someone a favor and preserving the planet in the process. (Carpet is a messy, energy-intensive product.)

For any smaller scraps left behind, Shimon Rura's answer is good.

Comment: Depending on where you live, you may not be allowed to set things out at the curb, except during trash collection times. Some places are more stuffy than others, particularly if you're governed by a HOA.

Comment: If you want it to be removed from the kerb, put a note on it saying something like "$50 - enquire within".

Answer (score 2):

If it's still in new condition, have you contacted your local Habitat for Humanity or other building material recycler? They might be interested in it and you can get a tax write off. Otherwise, you might be able to sell it or give it away on Craigslist. The last resort would be disposing of it

Comment: If Habitat can't use it in a house, they may be able to sell it via their Re/stores. Either way, I agree that this would be an excellent choice if they're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Contact a private waste disposal company. Your municipal trash collection service probably doesn't allow construction waste, but private companies exist that offer a range of waste collection services.

You can find them easily by looking for dumpster providers. If you don't need a dumpster, though, many will also accept waste drop-offs or pick up loads from your home. Your city's waste department may have a list of recommended private haulers as well.

Update: Looks like the [Sugarland, TX Garbage & Recycling Guidelines](http://www.sugarlandtx.gov/index.aspx?NID=1276#c) suggest you contact a company called Republic Services for disposal options.

Comment: Carpeting is not usually considered "construction waste".

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine once said, "I haven't found anything so useless that it won't disappear in a day after listing it for free on craigslist."

Now, years later, I never have either :)